# Unit testing a basic 'CreateUser' method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm in the process of learning unit testing, but a bit confused as to how to apply it to actual "real world" projects. The tutorials all seem to use a simple single class application, which makes the process of writing basic unit tests pretty simple. However when I try to apply it to an actual n-tier project I don't know where to begin. It seems I don't know what I should be writing unit tests for.

For example, the simple Action Controller method and class that accepts a user inputs and writes to database if valid:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    [StringLength(8, MinimumLength = 4, ErrorMessage = "UserName must be between 4 and 8 characters.")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel newUser)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _userRepository.AddNewUser(newUser);
    }   
    else
    {
        return View(newUser);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Approval");
}
```

I'm trying to determine what I should be writing unit tests for, or even what unit tests are possible to write for the above example?

- Test that the Action Method returns the correct view?
- Do I write unit tests that confirm that user inputs are valid, or do
  I assume that the MVC DataAnnotations will cover that?
- What about the writing a valid user to the database? Should I test
  this (or is this even possible?

What else am I missing?

Comment: You should strive to test that the unit functions correctly, and by that I mean that you must decide what you would require it to do in order to function completely. For instance, if the unit is supposed to vet and disqualify invalid user creations (invalid characters in the user name, etc.) then that's something I would test. You should also mock out the underlying data repository and test that the unit, when given valid data, actually attempts to persist the created user.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to know what we are testing.  If we are unit testing then I would have separate fixtures per class/system under test.  When I say fixture, I mean all the tests for a given class.

In a unit testing scenario this would be a fixture for the viewmodel, to verify the validations are working correctly and a fixture for the controller which owns the Register method.

So for a controller action method you are going to want to test both branches of the logic.  So in the fixture I'd have a tests for

```
    [Test]
    public void should_redirect_to_aprroval_on_post_for_create()
    {
        //Assert
        A.CallTo(() => _fakeUserRepository.Save(A<Athlete>.Ignored));
        //Act
        var result = (RedirectToRouteResult) _sut.Create(new RegisterViewModel{});

        //Assert
        Assert.That(result.RouteValues["action"], Is.EqualTo("Approval"));
    }
```

this test will mock out the UserRepository using a mocking framework.  The syntax here is FakeItEasy

I'll then test that the other branch

```
    [Test]
    public void should_return_same_view_when_model_is_invalid_on_post_for_create()
    {
        //Arrrange
        _sut.ModelState.AddModelError(String.Empty, String.Empty);

        //Act
        var result = (ViewResult) _sut.Create(new RegisterViewModel());

        //Assert
        Assert.That(result.ViewName, Is.EqualTo(String.Empty));
        Assert.That(result.Model.GetType(), Is.EqualTo(typeof (RegisterViewModel)));
    }
```

you could go a step further and check that all the values from the return view are correct.

It would be good to include your controller constructor to know what dependencies we will have to mock.

as for integration testing (testing against the database) I'd probably then create a separate testing project with SpecFlow and Selenium that runs against a live site and database.